# How to get Query object to felogin repository?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

i need Query object of TYPO3\CMS\Felogin\Controller\FrontendLoginController in my extention repository so i can create my own query conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Below code is useful to you

```
$query = $this->persistenceManager->createQueryForType('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser');
```

Write in this your extension repository.